# Unable to connect to Node.js in Vagrant

Tags: node.js, vagrant, portforwarding

I am trying to set up a Node.js app using Vagrant. There is also a Rails app inside that very same Vagrant box, which works OK. Node is using port 3001, so here are the config settings in Vagrantfile:

```
  # Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
  config.vm.box = "puppetlabs/ubuntu-14.04-32-puppet"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 4567, guest: 3000
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 5678, guest: 3001
```

So, I started Node in Vagrant box. This shows that inside the Vagrant box it responds to requests on port 3001:

```
vagrant@localhost:~$ wget 127.0.0.1:3001
--2014-12-24 06:37:40--  http://127.0.0.1:3001/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:3001... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
```

The guest machine is listening to port 3001:

```
$ sudo netstat -ltpn | grep 3001
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1422/node
```

The host is listening to port 5678:

```
sudo netstat -ltpn | grep 5678
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5678            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30966/VBoxHeadless
```

And yet, I can't connect to the app from the host browser.

What can be the problem?

**Updated:** Output on `vagrant up`:

```
[default] Forwarding ports...
[default] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
[default] -- 3000 => 4567 (adapter 1)
[default] -- 3001 => 5678 (adapter 1)
```

Comment: when you run the command `vagrant up` do you see output in console that looks something like `==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 5678 => 3001 (adapter 1)`

Comment: Yes. I updated my question to include the output of `vagrant up`

Answer (score 13):

Got the answer from a colleague.

Turned out, the node server in vagrant was listening to localhost, while it should have been listening to 0.0.0.0:

so this line in www file:

`var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), 'localhost', function() {`

had to be changed to:

`var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), '0.0.0.0', function() {`

All's working now.

Comment: Hi and Thanks a lot!!!! This is not recent but helped me as I had the same issue. But, I don't understand why this work on 0.0.0.0? Someone can tell?

Comment: Thanks, mate! This works for me too! I used before "localhost" and "127.0.0.1", but only "0.0.0.0" helped

Comment: changing 'localhost' to '0.0.0.0' worked for me: http-server ./app -a 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -c-1

Comment: I'm also very curious why this works. 0.0.0.0 is not a valid address for any host right? Weird.